# Running kubernetes command in cloud console returns timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The command I run is simply `kubectl get ns`

It works if I run the k8s command from my local terminal configured the k8s context. But when using the cloud console, it returns timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Check the organization & project name where you have logged in with cloud console.

You may also go to kuberenets cluster page and click on connect--> run in cloud console. This will get connected with right terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same command on my project and I got a message which said “Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443: i/o timeout” I believe that was the same message that you got. As per my understanding, it could be due to your cloud shell being connected/pointing to a different context which may be restricted or may doesn’t exist anymore. You can confirm it running this command on your cloud shell:

```
kubectl config current-context
```

If you see a different context in cloud shell, it could be changed to your current context running the next command:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME --zone CLUSTER_ZONE
```

Change the uppercase values for your current cluster name and the zone or region where it is located, if your cluster is in a region it will be necessary to change the tag --zone for --region.